# What is the label attribute of <option> really used for?

Tags: xhtml, attributes, specifications

According to the [w3 XHTML specification](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp), the `label` attribute specifies a shorter label for the option. However (using [the try-it tool](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_option) with FF3.5), I can't see any effect. Hence my question: what does this attribute really do?

**EDIT**
It seems that it overrides the label used in the dropdown list. The contents of the option are (as far as I know) only used as the default for the `value`. Does this (in IE7+) make the following two declarations equivalent?

```
<option label="Volvo">Volvo (Latin for 'I roll')</option>
```

and

```
<option label="Volvo" value="Volvo (Latin for 'I roll')">Whatever....</option>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ***label*** attribute defines a shorter version of the text which will appear for its option in the drop-down list of the select menu.

***label*** is defined as an optional attribute of the ***option*** tag, meaning implementation of and support for the attribute is not required to be compliant with the W3C standard.  More information can be found here about the ***option*** tag:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_label.asp

And, here is the link to the W3C specification:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#edef-OPTION

---

(Edit):
@Martijn the only usefulness I see is that it allows the developer to define an option tag and the label sets the "viewable text", and close it shorthand, rather than having to also specify a separate closing *option* tag.  This would result in less code/data sent to the browser/device, which might have implications in mobile applications.

Comment: This is exactly the documentation I'm linking to in the questeion. Sure, I've seen that it's not required. Still was wondering what it's for.

Comment: @Martijn, I updated my answer to indicate what I think this feature would be useful for if it were implemented fully in browsers.  Maybe this changes your opinion of my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Note: The label attribute is only supported by IE 7+. Try in IE and you will see the difference.

Comment: Agreed, ignore this attribute: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_label.asp